# How can Ansible "register" in a variable the result of including a playbook?

Tags: ansible

How can an [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) playbook [`register`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables) in a variable the result of [including](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) another playbook?

For example, would the following register the result of executing `tasks/foo.yml` in `result_of_foo`?

```
tasks:
  - include: tasks/foo.yml
  - register: result_of_foo
```

How else can Ansible record the result of a task sequence?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is that this can't be done.

The [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) statement is used to store the output of a single task into a variable.  The exact contents of the registered variable can vary widely depending on the type of task (for example a `shell` task will include stdout & stderr output from the command you run in the registered variable, while the `stat` task will provide details of the file that is passed to the task).

If you have an include file with an arbitrary number of tasks within it then Ansible would have no way of knowing what to store in the variable in your example.

Each individual task within your include file can register variables, and you can reference those variables elsewhere, so there's really no need to even do something like this.

Comment: There is a need if you treat a playbook like an opaque box (i.e. a function) with a simple, well-defined interface.  Why shouldn't a playbook have scoped variables and return values?

Comment: Ansible playbook suffers from some of the problems that I've observed in other domain specific languages (DSLs) such as Ant, a build language for Java.  Such languages are mostly declarative, but also have incomplete functional or imperative behaviour.  Ansible playbook has been incrementally filling in the imperative gaps, but as this case demonstrates, still has holes to fill.  An alternative approach is to base the design of a DSL on an existing programming language, but follow a narrower syntax or provide only specific functions.  (YAML and XML are *not* programming languages.)

Comment: Is this still not possible even if there is only a single task in a playbook? Could you register the result of that task, and then reference it back in the original playbook?

Answer (score 13):

I was able to do this by passing a variable name as a variable to be used in the task. I included my main.yaml and included cgw.yaml files below.

main.yaml:

```
- name: Create App A CGW
  include: cgw.yaml
  vars:
    bgp_asn: "{{ asn_spoke }}"
    ip_address: "{{ eip_app_a.public_ip }}"
    name: cgw-app-a
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ ec2_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ ec2_secret_key }}"
    register: cgw_app_a
```

cgw.yaml:

```
- name: "{{ name }}"
  ec2_customer_gateway:
    bgp_asn: "{{ bgp_asn }}"
    ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
    name: "{{ name }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  register: "{{ register }}"
```

Comment: that's a really interesting discovery so I was pleasantly surprised it works even with the latest released Ansible 2.7.6.
 
BUT it will stop working in 2.8. In ALL the three cases Ansible 2.8.0dev0  (just checked from Github) warns: "register" is not templatable, but we found: {{ ret }}, it will not be templated and will be used "as is".

Indeed, ret0 is not changed. So let it stay here for history but "do not use that in new designs" ;)

Comment: my comment relates to my edition of this answer which I reproduced in a Gist https://gist.github.com/mz0/4462cb7bdae37881a21660c5703a0fd2

Comment: @mz0, where this information about dropping support of pattern for `register` in Ansible 2.8? The [documentation for 2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) doesn't mention it.

Comment: @LeoY from cited WARNING:  "register" is not templatable, but we found: {{ ret }}, it will not be templated and will be used "as is"

Comment: @mz0, can you provide a proof link? in the documentation link that I found there is no such warning. is it a comment in the code?