# Notify handler or register ansible variable when change is detected in include_role?

Tags: variables, include, ansible, roles

After lots of searching, I come to the conclusion that ansible (I use the latest stable as of now version, v2.5.3) most likely does not support registering variables or notifications from `include_role` and `import_role` statements.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701062/how-can-ansible-register-in-a-variable-the-result-of-including-a-playbook) and the suggestion in one of the answers is: `Each individual task within your include file can register variables, and you can reference those variables elsewhere`.

However, if I follow this suggestion then I need to add extra unnecessary code in all of my included roles, just because I may need a workaround in a *special* server. Things can quickly get out of control and become messy, especially in the case of nested role inclusions (i.e. when an included role contains more included roles). Moreover, if I use roles from ansible-galaxy, I would want to stick to the upstream versions (treat the roles as external libraries), meaning that ideally I would not want to change the code of the *role* as it does not sound very intuitive to have to maintain forks of all the roles one has to use (otherwise the *external roles/libraries* pretty much lose their meaning).

So what is the suggested solution for such a problem when one wants to reuse code from external roles, and based on if any change happened by the called role do something? Am I thinking totally wrong here in terms of how I have implemented my ansible playbook logic?

Take a look at the following **concrete example of what I'm trying to do**:

I have split tasks that I want to reuse in smaller roles. In my `common` role I have an `add-file.yml` set of tasks that looks like this (`roles/common/tasks/add-file.yml`):

```
- name: Copying file "{{ file.src }}" to "{{ file.dest }}"
  copy:
    src: "{{ file.src }}"
    dest: "{{ file.dest }}"
    owner: "{{ file.owner | default(ansible_user_id) }}"
    group: "{{ file.group | default(ansible_user_id) }}"
    mode: "{{ file.mode | default('preserve') }}"
  when:
    file.state is not defined or file.state != 'absent'

- name : Ensuring file "{{ file.dest }}" is absent
  file:
    path: "{{ file.dest }}"
    state: "{{ file.state }}"
  when:
    - file.state is defined
    - file.state == 'absent'
```

This is basically a generic custom task to support `state: absent` for file copying until [this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29781) gets fixed.

Then in another role (let's call this `setup-XY`) I do this in the file `roles/setup-XY/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Copying X-file
  import_role:
    name: common
    tasks_from: add-file.yml
  vars:
    file:
      state: present
      src: X-file
      dest: /home/user/X-file
      mode: '0640'

- name: Ensuring Yline in Z-file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/default/Z-file
    regexp: '^Yline'
    line: 'Yline=123'
```

Then in a third role (let's call it `z-script`) I want something like this in the file `roles/z-script/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Setup-XY
  include_role:
    name: setup-XY
  register: setupxy

- name: Run Z script if setupXY changed
  shell: /bin/z-script
  when: setupxy.changed
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work since the `register: setupxy` line registers a `setupxy` variable that always returns `"changed": false`. If I use the `import_role` instead of `include_role`, the variable is not registered at all (remains undefined).

Note that in the `z-script` role I want to run the `/bin/z-script` shell command whenever any change is detected in the role `setup-XY`, i.e. if the `X-file` or `Z-file` were changed, and in reality I might be having many more tasks in the `setup-XY` role.

Moreover, note that the `z-script` is unrelated to the `setup-XY` role (e.g. the `z-script` only needs to run in a particular *problematic* server) so the code for executing the `z-script` ideally should not be shipped together with (and pollute) the `setup-XY` role. Look at the `setup-XY` as the external/upstream role in this case.

Comment: Hi, nice question. I can see Ansible as a series or playbooks calling roles (to me, a role is a reusable and standard way of distributing Ansible code). Importing or including roles inside another role is not the way IMHO of using Ansible. We have the metas to define roles dependencies and playbooks to orchestrate them. In my experience with Ansible, I have found unmanageable those roles with specific variables and calls to other external roles, plays, task, etc. Why not doing from a main playbook?

Comment: Sorry, but the answer you had already read is valid, no matter how much you don't like it.　Also [best-practice questions are considered too broad / requesting opinions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic) by many SO users, so try to ask well-defined programming questions.

Comment: @techraf I think the OP raised a valid point. Also, the quoted question is more than 2 years old - which by itself gives reason enough to look for alternatives. I fail to see the need to be snappy with your comment.

Comment: @jangroth ① SO is not for raising valid points, but for asking questions as defined in the Help Center and decided by the community.　② There is no time limit to questions, you can add an answer under the 2-y.o. question if you have one.　③ I closed the question as duplicate and explained OP  the reasoning. I don't know what's "snappy" about it, why you felt a need to call it that way, and what you wanted to achieve by that.

Comment: @techraf The existing question that I already included in my question is very limited and it's not that I *just* don't like the answer; The existing answer is simply not a solution for what I am asking and have thoroughly described in this question. Anyway, I updated the question slightly and not asking for `best practices` anymore. Now it is more concrete. I hope you will reconsider and open this question again. Thanks.

Comment: The answer (which is well-written and by no means "*very limited*") under the dup-target contains a simple and valid answer for your question: [The short answer is that this can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702282/2947502). With your subsequent edits ("*I should not touch the code of the role.*") you don't even need to read further.

Comment: With regards to the *should not touch the code of the role* just answer me one question please. When you use roles from ansible-galaxy do you drill down and make changes and try to maintain your own forks of the roles you use? Doesn't sound very intuitive. If someone has to do that then something is very wrong and the roles lose their meaning. It's like trying to use a library but before you use it you are instructed to modify the library's code. It's not that you can't do it, but there must be some way to achieve what you want by modifying your own code and not the library's code.

Comment: @VangelisTasoulas That's exactly the problem I have now.. Any updates on this? Is it still not possible to run custom handler on any task change happened within someone else's role used within play?

Comment: @Drew I haven't been working with ansible seriously for some time and I still don't have a solution for this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. You should understand that roles are like functions in other languages. You cannot rely on what happens internally.

That is why handlers are usable only in the current context, a role or a playbook and you cannot cross call them.