# ansible: Looping over directory and referencing that file in another playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make a playbook that loops over the number of files in a directory and then use those files in another playbook.
My playbook as it is now:

```
---

- name: Run playbooks for Raji's testing
  register: scripts
  roles:
    - prepare_edge.yml
    - prepare_iq.yml
    - scriptor.yml
  with_fileglob: ~/ansible/test_scripts/*
~
```

When I run this it doesn't work, I've tried "register: scripts" to make a variable to reference inside scriptor.yml but again the playbook fails. Any advice or help you can provide would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

P.S. I am super new to ansible

here is the scriptor.yml

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: Create directory
    command: mkdir /some/path/

  - name: If file is a playbook
    copy:
      src: "{{ scripts }}"
      dest: /some/path/
    when: "{{ scripts }}" == "*.yml"

  - name: if file is a script
    shell: . ${{ scripts }}
    when: "{{ scripts }}" == "*.sh"
```

P.S.S prepare_edge.yml and prepare_iq.yml don't reference anything and just need to be called in the loop before scriptor.yml

here is the error:

```
ERROR! 'register' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/Users/JGrow33/ansible/raji_magic_playbook.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Run playbooks for Raji's testing
  ^ here
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to use `register` or where you're trying to access the reigstered variable. If your playbook is failing with an error, please include that error in your question.

Comment: I've updated it to the original playbook and added the error i've been getting. If i take register: scripts out, I get the same error but with "with_fileglob is not a valid attribute...."

Answer (score 0):

There error message you're getting is telling you that you can't run `register` in a Playbook.

You can accomplish what you're looking for by doing something like the following in your scriptor.yml file:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: Create directory
    command: mkdir /some/path/

  - name: If file is a playbook
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /some/path/
    with_fileglob: ~/ansible/test_scripts/*.yml

  - name: if file is a script
    shell: . ${{ item }}
    with_fileglob:         copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /some/path/
    with_fileglobe: ~/ansible/test_scripts/*.sh
```

**References**

[How can Ansible "register" in a variable the result of including a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701062/how-can-ansible-register-in-a-variable-the-result-of-including-a-playbook)

Comment: If I do it this way, wouldn't the main playbook not loop?

Comment: you didn't include your other roles, do they need to be called before every file?

Comment: yeah, prepare_edge.yml and prepare_iq.yml need to be called before scriptor.yml every time scriptor.yml either runs a script or copies a playbook. That was why i was trying to make the loop in the main playbook so everything got called at every step of the loop

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be in separate roles?  You could consolidate the three.

Comment: I was asked to make it so that there were 3 different playbooks. I am an intern and I was asked to automate some scripts used for testing as a project. The different playbooks makes it easier to edit later on if more stuff needs to be added.