# How to store MySQL password on remote host in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Using the mysql_user module, I store the new password in a file, however, it stores it on my localhost. I want to save it to the **remote** host instead. How can I send the file to the /tmp/ directory on the remote machine?

```
- name: Create MySQL user on Dev
  mysql_user:
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    login_host: my_remote_host
    login_user: "{{ MYSQL_USER }}"
    login_password: "{{ MYSQL_PASS }}"
    name: "{{ name }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('password', '/tmp/new_password.txt chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation length=10') }}"
    host: 192.168.%
    priv: '*.*:ALTER,ALTER ROUTINE,CREATE,CREATE ROUTINE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,CREATE VIEW,DELETE,DROP,EVENT,EXECUTE,GRANT OPTION,INDEX,INSERT,LOCK TABLES,PROCESS,SELECT,SHOW DATABASES,SHOW VIEW,TRIGGER,UPDATE'
    state: present
```

I have a feeling I cannot register the password parameter according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702282/4522447) answer, so I am editing my question.

Comment: The basic problem of having sensitive data deployed is handled by: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-vault.html

Comment: It's not something that needs to be stored in the vault. I just need to either 1) cat the file on localhost, 2) or store the file on the remote host instead.

Comment: Use a `copy` task?

Comment: @larsks I have no idea why I didn't think of that with as many times as I've used that module. Worked perfectly. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Sure, happy to. All set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ansible, `lookup` runs on the control host where Ansible is running. There's no way to have the `password` lookup create the file directly on the remote host.

You could use the `copy` module after generating your password:

```
- name: Create MySQL user on Dev
  mysql_user:
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    login_host: my_remote_host
    login_user: "{{ MYSQL_USER }}"
    login_password: "{{ MYSQL_PASS }}"
    name: "{{ name }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('password', '/tmp/new_password.txt chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation length=10') }}"
    host: 192.168.%
    priv: '*.*:ALTER,ALTER ROUTINE,CREATE,CREATE ROUTINE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,CREATE VIEW,DELETE,DROP,EVENT,EXECUTE,GRANT OPTION,INDEX,INSERT,LOCK TABLES,PROCESS,SELECT,SHOW DATABASES,SHOW VIEW,TRIGGER,UPDATE'
    state: present

- name: copy password file to remote host
  copy:
    src: /tmp/new_password.txt
    dest: /tmp/new_password.txt
```

But using a `template` task to e.g. generate a `my.cnf` file on the remote would also be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a template task

```yaml
  - name: Save mysql password file
    template:
      src: mysql.j2
      dest:  /tmp/mysql-password-file
```

**mysql.j2**

```
{{ password }}
```

Comment: Where does `{{ password }}` come from?

Comment: That would be a variable. Where are you getting your password currently and how are you storing it? I see you have a variable set "{{ MYSQL_PASS }}" in your sample. Just change the variable name in the jinja template to {{ MYSQL_PASS }} or to whatever variable name you are using to hold the mysql password.

Comment: {{ MYSQL_PASS }} is to login to MySQL. The `password` parameter in the task is to generate a new password for the new user. But I figured it out using the `copy` module.